# How to iterate through a list based on elements of another list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two Lists. Imagine something like:

```
List<string> firstList = {"ab","bb","cd","ed","fe","ff","eg","lh","di","dj"}

List<string> secondList = {"ab","fe","lh","dj"}
```

I need to iterate through the firstList and "do something" for every element that exists in the secondList. Possible? Please note that in the `"do something` part, I need to `Add` next element of `firstList` to another third `List`. Please guide.

My working is:

```
for (int g = 0; g < row_2.Count; g++)
{
     for (int h = 0; h < d["topHeadings"].Count; h++)
     {
         if (row_2[g] == d["topHeadings"][h])
         {
             while ((row_2[g] != d["topHeadings"][h + 1]))
                    {
                           row_2_1.Add(row_2[g + 1]);
                            g++;
                    }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the index they appear at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `All` and `Contains`:

```
bool allInFirst = secondList.All(entry => firstList.Contains(entry));
```

This is `true` if *all* elements in `secondList` are also contained in `firstList`.

---

According to your comment, you want something completely different than your question asks for. It seems you want to iterate through the `firstList` and "do something" for every element that exists in the `secondList`, so you can do this:

```
foreach(var element in firstList.Where(secondList.Contains))
     // do something with element
```

This filters `firstList` for elements that exist in `secondList` and iterates over them. Maybe I misunderstood you again and you want it the other way round, so simply exchange `firstList` and `secondList`.

---

If you need the indices maybe the best way is this:

```
for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < firstList.Count; firstIndex++)
{
    int secondIndex = secondList.IndexOf(firstList[firstIndex]);
    if (secondIndex < 0) continue;
    // do what you need with firstList[firstIndex] and the indices 
}
```

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to iterate `secondList` and pick first element of `secondList` and iterate `firstList` and check if there is a match, if yes, do something till the next element of `secondList`. Can you please guide? Thank

Comment: @RehanKhan I read your question, it says "check when each element of secondList is present in firstList". That's what my and fubo's code does.

Comment: @RehanKhan Updated my answer. I hope I understood you correctly this time.

Comment: Thanks Rene. Yes thats what I meant and your given solution is correct BUT in `//do something with element` part, I want to add next element to a list. Is that possible for foreach? We're almost there.

Comment: In other words, we need the `index` of the `firstList` as well.

Comment: @RehanKhan updated my answer. sorry, but that will be my last try, I don't like moving targets ;)

Answer (score 3):

By using `Except`

```
List<char> firstList = new List<char>() { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' };
List<char> secondList = new List<char>() { 'a', 'd', 'e', 'j' };
bool Result = secondList.Except(firstList).Any();
```

This is `true` if there are elements in `secondList` that are not in `firstList`

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to iterate `secondList` and pick first element of `secondList` and iterate `firstList` and check if there is a match, if yes, do something till the next element of `secondList`. Can you please guide? Thanks

Comment: @RehanKhan that's another question

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a third option, you could use a `HashSet<T>` as second collection, then you have the right method already on board: [`HashSet<T>.IsSubsetOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HashSet<char> secondChars = new HashSet<char>() { 'a', 'd', 'e', 'j' };
bool allSecondInFirst = secondChars.IsSubsetOf(firstList);
```

You can initialize the set on the fly by passing the list to the constructor:

```
HashSet<char> secondChars = new HashSet<char>(secondList);
```

But it's more efficient to work with the set in the first place if duplicates aren't allowed anyway.

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to iterate `secondList` and pick first element of `secondList` and iterate `firstList` and check if there is a match, if yes, do something till the next element of `secondList`. Can you please guide? Thank

Answer (score 1):

My code is more extensive than the others, but it's a basic example of how iterate a list and return true when you have a coincidence between both lists:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
        List<string> secondList = new List<string>() { "a", "c", "e" };
        bool elementFound = false;
        int countFirst = 0;
        int countSecond = 0;

        while ((countFirst < firstList.Count) && (!elementFound))
        {
            elementFound = false;

            while ((countSecond < secondList.Count) && (!elementFound))
            {
                if (secondList[countSecond] == firstList[countFirst])
                {
                    elementFound = true;
                }

                countSecond++;
            }

            if (!elementFound)
            {
                countFirst++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("We have found an element from the second list in the first one.");
        Console.WriteLine("The element is: {0}", firstList[countFirst]);
        Console.WriteLine("Pos: {0}", countFirst);
```

Of course, I've made the example with a string List.

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to iterate `secondList` and pick first element of `secondList` and iterate `firstList` and check if there is a match, if yes, do something till the next element of `secondList`. You soultion is giving me the correct output but only for the first element of the `secondList` while I need it to do the same for all the elements in `secondList`. Can you please guide? Thank

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons you might want to use a HashSet. Something like this:

```
var elementsFromFirstList = new HashSet<int>(firstList);
secondList.Where(elem => elementsFromFirstList.Contains(elem)); // these are all elements that are present in the first list and the second list
```

Alternatively do:

```
secondList.Intersect(firstList); // these are all elements that are present in the first list and the second list
```

EDIT: 
If you want the index of the element in the first list, you could use the IndexOf method. However this might not give you the wanted performance. I would suggest something like this:

```
var index = 0;
var indexByElement = firstList.ToDictionary(elem => elem, elem => index++);
foreach(var elem in secondlist.Where(indexByElement.ContainsKey))
{
    var index = indexByElement[elem];
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Please read the question again. I want to iterate `secondList` and pick first element of `secondList` and iterate `firstList` and check if there is a match, if yes, do something till the next element of `secondList`. Can you please guide? Thank

Comment: @RehanKhan I edited the answer. Still I am not sure if I understand the question correctly.